# Call closure's delegate method from a function in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, delegates, closures, gradle

In a Gradle script I have a Groovy closure with a delegate, and I have created a function calling methods on that delegate as described below:

```
// Simplified example
ant.compressFiles() {
    addFile(file: "A.txt")
    addFile(file: "B.txt")
    addAllFilesMatching("C*.txt", getDelegate())
}

def addAllFilesMatching(pattern, closureDelegate) {
    // ...
    foundFiles.each {
        closureDelegate.addFile(file: it)
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this in a prettier way, without having to pass the delegate to a function? Is it for example possible to somehow extend the delegate with new methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be solved by creating a function that returns a `Closure`:

```
ant.compressFiles() addAllFilesMatching("A.txt", "B.txt", "C*.txt")

Closure addAllFilesMatching(String... patterns) {
    // Calculate foundFiles from patterns...
    return {
        foundFiles.each { foundFile ->
            addFile(file: foundFile)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can declare the closure first, set its `delegate`, `resolveStrategy` and then pass it to `each`:

```
def addAllFilesMatching(pattern, delegate) {

  def closure = {
    addFile file: it
  }

  closure.delegate = delegate
  closure.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST

  foundFiles = ["a.txt", "b.txt", "c.txt", "d.txt"]

  foundFiles.each closure
}
```

Comment: That might work, but since it requires more code and I still need to pass the delegate to the function, I don't really think this qualifies as prettier.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

This is a minute modification to WillP's answer (which is absolutely correct and the way should be done) and should be prettier (as per your request) because it uses a closure instead of a method.

```
def addAllFilesMatching = {pattern ->
    // ... foundFiles based on pattern
    foundFiles.each {
        delegate.addFile(file: it)
    }
}

ant.compressFiles() {
    addFile(file: "A.txt")
    addFile(file: "B.txt")

    addAllFilesMatching.delegate = getDelegate() 
    addAllFilesMatching("C*.txt")
}
```

Comment: `delegate.addFile` could just as well be just `addFile`, right? While it is better, I still don't think it's a big improvement in terms of code complexity. I was hoping for some magic way to just make my function access the delegate (or similar), but maybe non better exists.

Comment: @DavidPärsson Well there is huge difference when `delegate` is manipulated in a closure. Try to [run this sample](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5881575/) in Groovy console or Groovy Web console to see the difference.